# Language Support selection menu doesn't show the language I've installed

Tags: 19.04, language-support

I have installed the language **Khmer**, but it's not showing up in the Language Support selection menu.

How can I solve this problem?

[image: Language Support dialog and Installed Languages dialog]

Comment: did you check in `Region & Language` from system settings?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XPbe.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSnxO.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPi8S.png, I can not found what's wrong with my pc :(

Comment: start typing and then select `other`

Comment: When I try with other language, it works fine.

Comment: click 3 vertical dots in your above linked image and type khmer

Comment: Yeah, It really works. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @PRATAP: These comments mix up display language with input language, so their value as user guidance are limited. But the OP apparently looked for a suitable input method, so well...

Comment: @Zanna after reading GunnarHjalmarsson's comment.. I thought to post bcoz his comment is very well valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gunnar Hjalmarsson for [guidance on this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189066/language-support-selection-menu-doesnt-show-the-language-ive-installed?noredirect=1#comment1988393_1189066).

There are two main things here:

1. Display Language
2. Input Language

*Display Language* needs to be installed via **Language Support** (there could be other ways also)

[image: Language Support dialog]

[image: select language]

[image: Khmer working]

[image: selecting layout]

For *Input Language* you don't need to install anything. You just need to select it via **Region & Language** (There could be other ways also)

[image: search in GNOME shell for region & language and select]